# How can I make my input make a random selection

Tags: python, random, input

I need to to figure out how much the viewer spent watching one of the items in my dictionary. First I need to allow them to input how many viewers, which I got. But then I have to have each viewer them randomly select an item (it is allowed to duplicate).

Then show the total time that was spent on ever item that each viewer spent time on. Finally I need to show the total amount of time spent between all the items/vids that all viewers watched, as well as which
items were watched by the viewers (can't be duplicated). I'm very confused on where to begin.

Code:

```
n = int(input())
my_dict = {}


for i in range(n):
    titles=input("What is the ")
    length=int(input("What is length?")) # You were taking the input of length as a string. 
    my_dict[titles] = length
print ("You have", n," on your. The names of your are:", my_dict)


shortest = min(my_dict.values())
longest = max(my_dict.values())

print("Your shortest video is", shortest,"minutes long.")
print("Your longest video is", longest,"minutes long.")


average = sum(my_dict.values())/ len(my_dict)


print("Your average length is", average)


sub = 0
while sub >= 0:
    sub = int(input("How many subscribers do you currently have? "))




if sub >= 0:
    print('Histogram:')
    for i in range(sub):
        choice = random.choice(list(my_dict))
        for i in range(choice):
                print('*', end=' ')
    print('\n')
```

I'm working on finding a solution, but I don't know where to start so thinking I might as well post here first in case I can't find the answer. (Also I don't need to demonstrate this first part with a histogram technically, I thought it would just be easy, if you have another idea please let me know!)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have understood, you want to know the no. of viewers then get a random video. Finally, tell the amount of time they have spent watching that video,total time spend on each video(by all viewers), and at last total time spent(by all viewers in watching all videos). Correct me If I am wrong. You can use the following code:

```
n = int(input())
my_dict = {}


for i in range(n):
    titles=input("What is the ")
    length=int(input("What is length?")) # You were taking the input of length as a string. 
    my_dict[titles] = length
print ("You have", n," on your. The names of your are:", my_dict)


shortest = min(my_dict.values())
longest = max(my_dict.values())

print("Your shortest video is", shortest,"minutes long.")
print("Your longest video is", longest,"minutes long.")


average = sum(my_dict.values())/ len(my_dict)


print("Your average length is", average)



sub = int(input("How many subscribers do you currently have? "))
total_time = 0 
total_time_eachvid = {}


if sub >= 0:
    print('Histogram:')
    for i in range(sub):
        choice = random.choice(list(my_dict))
        if choice in total_time_eachvid:
            total_time_eachvid[choice] += my_dict[choice] #If the video was already selected by a viewer once then add the time.
        else:
            total_time_eachvid[choice] = my_dict[choice] #If the video appears for first time then enter the length of the video.
        print("You have spent", my_dict[choice], "time.") # Printing the time or length of the video that the viewer selected(got randomly).
        total_time += my_dict[choice]
    print('\n')
print("Total Time spent by all viewers is:", total_time)
print("Total time spent on each video", total_time_eachvid)
```